# Connection to WLAN cause trouble on other network

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have this weird problem with different WLAN's:

- I have a laptop owned by university A, with user credentials for their LAN
- I also have access to 'eduroam', a WLAN that is available at almost every university in Europe
- There is one particular institute (let's say university B) that's causing trouble. If I connect to eduroam there, everything works just fine.
- Whenever I go home and use the home WLAN, I have internet connection, but no connection to other PC's on the network.
- Then I connect to university A again, and connect to their LAN
- When I get home (WLAN), everything works fine again.

It's almost as if university B screws up some settings, which are fixed by connecting to the LAN of university A. I haven't got a clue what it might be.

Some additional info:
 * Laptop OS: Windows XP SP2
 * Other home PC OS: Windows 7 (usually network traffic is working fine)
 * In the "broken" state, `ping` between the laptop and home computer (in any direction) results in 100% loss of packages. `ping`-ing the router, however, works fine (internet also works fine).

When trying to mount a network share to `\\<computername>\<sharename>`, windows returns

```
An error occured while reconnecting Z: to \\<computername>\<sharename>
Microsoft Windows Network : The local device name is already in use.
This connection has not been restored
```

Trying to navigate to `\\computername` with explorer returns

```
Windows cannot find '\\<computername>\'. Check the spelling and try again, 
or try searching for the item by clicking the Start button and then clicking Search
```

Comment: Is the IP range used at Uni B eduroam the same as the IP range you use at home?

Comment: @Paul: not sure, but `ipconfig` indicates that back home the IP is from the range used by the home router. I'll be sure to check the IP range of Uni B next time I'm there.

Answer (score 2):

When you get home, and the laptop is in the broken state:

- Open a command prompt
- Type **ipconfig /release**
- Then **ipconfig /renew**

This should reset all the settings from the old setup and grab new settings from your home setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll definately try this next time I have the problem. Thanks

Comment: This does not solve the problem (sorry): it appears the connection is reinitiated, but the problem persists (also after an additional reboot)

Comment: Maybe I should add that I use wireless LAN at home.